# Possible fishbone identification

Tags: species-identification

It's my first post to this forum so I really hope, my question is not misplaced here!

I found this item on the beach [La Línea de la Concepción, Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_L%C3%ADnea_de_la_Concepci%C3%B3n) and it resembles pictures I found of certain spine bones of larger fish. Acutally, I have no idea about any of that and as far as I know, it could be some piece of pottery washed by the sea into this shape.

Interesting is the small "V"-shaped mark. The object is 5.5cm in diameter.

Thx for your helping me identifing this object!

[image: Front]
[image: Back]
[image: Side]
[image: Close-up]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Not an expert, but that is almost certainly not a `fish vertebra` (try an image search) —  looks like part of a ceramic to me.

Comment: agree with Tyresome, the texture is all wrong for a vertebra especially the broken portions, a piece of shell is more likely. bone has a very recognizable porous texture, massive or solid texture like that is either shell or man made.

Comment: In addition, the reddish coloration is the result of iron oxide - used in the glaze probably, or possibly iron from the clay. There is also a very clear "V" mark in images 1 and 4 - this has been stamped in. Definitely man-made.

Comment: It might be the base of a broken ceramic mug or vase; @bob1 has provided excellent evidence of it's origin. That is a [maker's mark](https://www.poplarforest.org/268-2/) (I used to throw pottery before the pandemic and makers marks were required to identify which piece of pottery belonged to whom coming out of the community kiln.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely man-made. It has none of the features of a natural (biological) product and several features of man-made.

First - it has impressions on a smooth surface. In nature, smooth surfaces such as the interface between bones tend to be completely smooth, with no impressions or shapes that might cause friction. This has two features that appear man-made - the "V" which appears stamped in and might help an expert identify where, and who (company) made this. On the obverse (image 2) of the V surface are two shapes that appear like blobs or holes (at the "10" and "1" positions; if the object were a clock). I suspect that these are from the manufacture and that this object is made using a ceramic method known as [slip-casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_casting), which is where liquid clay (slip) is injected into a mold and allowed to set before firing. This technique produces a form of stoneware which is cheap and highly reproducible, so it is used for most ceramics these days. If you have a mug or plate handy - have a look on the bottom, you'll likely find similar shapes to those on this object (on my mugs it tends to be the bottom of the handle often smoothed a bit). This is where the slip has been injected into the mold.

Second - The reddish coloration on the surface is highly likely to be iron oxide. This could come from two sources in man-made objects. One of these sources is a [glaze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_glaze). In ceramics glazes are often used to create smooth, impermeable surfaces and are frequently made with metal oxides, but this would create a more even surface coloration, so I suspect that it is iron oxide present in the clay from which this was cast. On this object, most of the glaze has worn off, but you can still see the residue inside the "V" mark, which is shiny. This is a clear glaze making it likely to be a [lead-glaze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead-glazed_earthenware). Lead glazes are very commonly used on ceramics for their clear and shiny effect.

Third - this has fracture patterns consistent with ceramics rather than bone. I'm struggling to find things to illustrate this, but ceramics and stones chip in remarkably similar ways, with chips coming off the edges, leaving sharply delineated edges and rounded spall. Bones tend to chip in a more jagged manner.

Fourth - the texture is wrong for bone. Bone texture tends to be porous when broken, but yours looks crystalline (not easy to see in the images though), which is not a characteristic of bone, but might be for something like a sea-shell from a gastropod or mollusc.

Conclusion: Man-made stoneware ceramic, not biological.